# Why jQuery throws errors when used with bootstrap 4 and a masonry plugin when the screen width is under 576 px?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeerror

I'm using bootstrap4.masonry.js on a website I'm building. I want to load some content via ajax. It works when the width of the screen is > 575px.

When the width of the screen is 575px or less, it doesn't work and the errors below are threw.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $cols.eq is not a function
at add (bootstrap4.masonry.js:19)
at Object.push (bootstrap4.masonry.js:53)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):1293)
at Function.each (jquery.js?1579106077:354)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js?1579106077:189)
at Object.<anonymous> ((index):1290)
at fire (jquery.js?1579106077:3268)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?1579106077:3398)
at done (jquery.js?1579106077:9305)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js?1579106077:9548)
```

I know 575px is a 'breakpoint' in bootstrap 4 and I think it's related. But I don't know how and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the bootstrap.masonry.js plugin. It was quickly fixed by the author of the plugin.